# Tips on making a no-chill IPA

Tags: ipa, biab, no-chill

Due to space and time constraints, I have been using BIAB and no-chill.

I'm satisfied with the results I get with most of my brews, but never got a good IPA.

In special, my brews lack the pungent hop aroma.

I usually do a single bittering addition @ 60m (start of boil). 
Any tips on how to get a very hoppy IPA using no-chill?

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you do a basic bittering addition, then do a massive "flameout/cube" hopping, like 3-4oz of something pungent. Ferment with a clean yeast, and that will give you some idea of a baseline for non-dry-hopped hop aroma and flavor. I did this basically with EKG once, and it was underwhelming, but good hoppy beers are tough to nail and it could have been something else for me. I'd recommend pitching as soon as your cube comes down to pitching temps, don't wait around for a few days as this might degrade the hop aroma from the cube-hopping.

After you get the baseline for the cube-hopping, obviously you can work on extra dry-hopping to punch up the aroma.

Comment: sorry, graham, whats EKG?

Comment: @jards - East Kent Goldings

Comment: thanks, sometimes I feel somewhat lost in the acronyms, specially those like IMO, AFAIK, etc., and was expecting some like that.

Comment: What did you use for bittering?

Comment: A small does of Magnum, I believe, since its clean. I was ultimately not able to determine much from that one trial, but you might have better luck.

Answer (score 2):

I made a great Falconers Flight IPA using no chill last winter.  I simply added a sufficient bittering charge 40-50 IBUs at 60 minutes.  Then added 3 oz of pellets at Flameout. Put the lid on and walked away.  I transferred to the fermentor the next day.  With a couple days left in fermentation I added another 2 oz of FF pellets to the fermentor.  5 days later racked to a keg.  The beer had good aroma but great flavor.

I tried the same concept with traditional chilling and got close to the flavor profile by adding the original flame out hops with 20 minutes left in the boil.  The profile was pretty close to the original no chill batch.

No chill lends itself to some nice long hopstanding for flavor.  But you still need a good dry hopping charge post fermentation to get the aroma you are looking for.